# How to encrypt Save Files without using a key?

Tags: encryption, binary

Say I made a simple program that takes a file `.dat` that is encrypted in **Binary Format**, then I decrypt it into a *byte array* and then everything is rewritten again into the file decrypted.

For Example:

*I've made a binary encryption algorithm.* => 0100100001100101001000000110100001100101011000...

But this is very very easy to decrypt...

Is there any way, that, if it's possible does not need any sort of key, to encrypt my save progress?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to encrypt saves? There are easier ways to cheat, for example when using memory modification. I would just compress them with zlib (put them into .gz), it would reduce size and prevent some of possible cheaters from modifying it.

Comment: Yeah, that could work I will find some information throughout the web. Thanks!

Comment: Try RSA. It is the one of the strongest encryption methods.

Comment: Nitpicking: What you are doing is an *encoding*, not an *encryption*.

Comment: (assuming this is for single player) Don't try to prevent cheating in a single player game, it's annoying both for you and for the player. And is ultimately useless.

Comment: "Binary format to a byte array then written to the file..." Binary format isn't really a format.  All files are binary. Unless you mean you literally saved '0' and '1' characters? That's just wasting time, doesn't add any security.

Comment: It is **not possible** to encrypt save files so that the user can't read or modify them. (Because, for example, they could just pause your game in a debugger right after it does the decryption!). However, you can make it harder (because opening a plain text file is really easy compared to finding the right moment to pause the game in a debugger). Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: More or less that's what I wanna do. For example, if someone wants to gain health, make it impossible for him.

Comment: @DanielBejar I just told you, you can't make it impossible, you can only make it harder.

Comment: @AhmetZambak RSA is not the appropriate choice for this. AES used in an authenticated encryption mode could be suitable.

Comment: @DanielBéjar What you need is authentication - not encryption. Using HMAC with the key hardcoded in your program could work. Of course the key could be extracted from your code, but no obfuscation method can ever be perfectly secured against reverse engineering.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY problem

Comment: Could you clarify, what's the point of not using a key? Normally you always use some kind of key for encryption.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In general you should never invent your own cryptographic algorithms, unless you have at least a PhD in both mathematics **and** computer science. But there are many good stock algorithms which have no known attacks and have free implementations in many programming languages. For example RC5, AES or Blowfish. Depending on which technology you use to develop your game, it might even offer secure encryption out-of-the-box.

However, the question is if encrypting savegames is a good idea.

First, when you have your game executable do the encryption and decryption, you have to include both the algorithm and the key in your game executable. That means a determined hacker can find them, extract them, and use them to build a savegame editor. So it can never be 100% secure.

Second, why do you want to do this anyway? When it is an online game, you should store the gamestate online where the players can not modify it. When it is an offline game, then why bother? A cheater can only hurt their own game experience at worst. The honest players who want to enjoy your game as intended won't be affected by this at all. On the other hand, allowing players to cheat can *add* value to your game. It allows players to experience the game in a different way which can just increase their long-term enjoyment of your game.

Comment: For obfuscation I'd rather use custom algorithms, not standard crypto. Crytographic security doesn't matter, since you can't keep the key safe from the attacker, and figuring out the custom algorithm is more work for the reverser.

Comment: Though I can't imagine someone coming up with something good in a few hours time. And you'd be wasting resources on something that you probably don't need.

Comment: An offline game can still have achievements, and some players are willing to cheat to earn those.

Comment: "When it is an offline game, then why bother?" What if it's a single-player game with online highscores?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat for a solo game with online achievements or online highscore cryptography isn't buying you much either. Anyway, the approach would be to have the event recorded during an online session (the user must be authenticated anyway, because otherwise to whom the highscores belong?). In order to go further, as to avoid memory manipulation, tampering the client or custom rogue clients, you will have to make the game more online - as to monitor what the user is doing and how is getting the score is getting. So, at the end it is an online game, just single-player.

Comment: "allowing players to cheat can add value to your game" - upvoted for this statement. I am really annoyed by games that decide to lock parts of the experience that I paid for until I achieve a certain level of mastery, and I am glad that in these cases, there are cheats available to unlock the full game. For instance, I am totally lost in the racing tournaments against the AI in the older *Need for Speed* parts; to me, the enjoyment was rather in driving through the varied landscapes, hence I usually skip the racing and unlock all maps and cars. A game that prevents this would just annoy me.

Comment: @tepples re-read and understand the third paragraph: if it's an offline game the user has access to *everything*. Any time you put into such save file obfuscation is time not put into making a game better.

Comment: I would like "unless you have at least a PhD in both mathematics and computer science" rewritten as "unless you have at least the knowledge that would be required to gain a PhD in both mathematics and computer science" (and even then, at least in Germany, courses are often full of stuff not related to crypto). One does not inherently need a degree to outperform PhDs.

Comment: @phresnel While you're technically right, a PhD is a standard metric of one's mastery of a theoretical subject, as awarded by trusted institutions. So it makes sense to use it as a shorthand for the amount of knowledge and skill needed to achieve the PhD. In other words: what the OP meant is clear enough :-)

Comment: What I wanted to say with the PhD sentence is that there are very few people in the world who have the qualifications to design encryption algorithms and unless you have good reason to believe that you are one of them, you aren't.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, as long as the rest of logic is still offline, there's dozens of different methods you can submit arbitrary scores, from cheating with resouces/life/energy/whatever, implementing perfect-play bots or plainly replacing just a single function that submits highscore so it would always submit max score.

Answer (score 10):

To encrypt and decrypt locally, you will need to store the key in your program, so people will be able to crack the encryption if they disassemble your code. There are tricks to obfuscate keys, but even with those a dedicated attacker will find the key and then post it online for all those who are less dedicated to see. The only thing encryption does prevent is people who use a hex editor - you can easily foil that with compression and anything that makes the file unreadable by an unzip program. E.g. add one byte in front of the data.

Alternatively you can append the md5 of the savefile at the end of the file, so you'll notice if a file has been tampered with. You can then use this to either refuse loading the savegame, or to flag support tickets appropriately so you don't waste time on issues caused by manually modified savegames. Again, this is trivial to circumvent by anyone who can read your code.

If you want something that can't be circumvented by someone who has access to the binaries on their device, you need to run part of the program on a server, which is under your control.

To answer your last question, a key plus encryption type just identifies the exact algorithm that needs to be applied to encrypt/decrypt. You cannot encrypt/decrypt data without an algorithm that defines how to do so.

Comment: Your second point is nice. It could also help track problems in the case of file corruption.

Answer (score 4):

Store a transformed SHA256 hash of the actual save data in the save file.

Compare the stored hash to the SHA256 value of the data as you load it.

If that doesn't match, they've cheated or corrupted the file.

**Edit to clarify:** this makes it *more difficult* to crack the anti-cheat system but *still possible*.

Comment: Nothing stops people from recalculating the hash after they made the modifications. Also, I don't understand why there are still people who advocate the broken MD5 algorithm with all its known cryptographic weaknesses when there are far better alternatives like SHA-256 (for signatures) or bcrypt (for passwords).

Comment: Simple and fast. thx!

Comment: Simple, fast, and completely broken.

Comment: @DeadMG It's broken by design, because the user has access to the binaries which must contain the key. Using a stronger hash or encrypting the file with something like AES would be a waste of resources, and bad design, because it provides **no added security**, but does add cost. +1 because the downvote is undeserved.

Comment: @Philipp because in this case MD5 is clearly superior to SHA-256. What is required by the described approach is a cheap checksum algorithm, which is exactly what MD5 is.

Comment: @Phillip, nothing also stops them from decrypting the save file and re-encrypting it themselves, provided that they can find the encryption logic. Either way, they can go and analyse the code to crack the anti-cheat. You're right about the SHA256. I'll change it. To be fair though, it's less likely to clash as the user is to bypass it.

Comment: This is not even encryption! All checksumming does is ensure data integrity.

Comment: @transistor09 if it's purely client side, we can't _ensure_ anything and a checksum works just as well as having the client encrypt the whole thing. Either way, it can be cracked.

Comment: @Lolums checksumming is **not encryption**.

Comment: @transistor09 I am aware of that and you ignored my point.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks men! Anyways, who would like to steal my shift* game :D

Answer (score 1):

I would use a standard encryption algorithm (because it makes it harder to perform crypto-analysis on the saved file) but not one of the top five most used, and hide it throughout your code (because it makes it harder to understand what algorithm it is and where is the key.)

To hide the encryption algorithm into your code: take an open source version, understand its flow (which functions call which others an in what sequence), then rename all variables, struct fields and function names (just to be sure) and spread the functions all over your codebase, in different objects and modules, possibly separating their execution temporally as well (perform one piece of the encryption, then do something else, then after some ms come back to it from a seemingly unrelated piece of code and perform another phase of the encryption, and so on.) The key can be hidden in the same way, as a number of seemingly unrelated constants throughout your classes, that are accessed at runtime by the various hidden parts of the encryption algorithm.

Whether all this makes economical sense is another topic altogether.

Comment: I don't know... Making it that harder for just a game... But thanks for the help! Ill try my best!